# Some trouble with getValue method in getting date in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

I had search for along, how to get a date in a cell with google apps script correcty, but I can not find. Please don't  offer `getDisplayValues()`, because date in a cell is in "dd.MM" format. I wrote a script. that takes the date in the cell, and then format it to "dd.MM.yy". But with the `getValue()` it comes out sloppy in the case where I have a cell date `25.03.2019`, and after receiving the script, and formatting it looks `24.03.2019`.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have a time zone issue. You likely want the spreadsheet and the script to be using the same time zone. You can do that in the [spreadsheet settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515) and in the project properties menu of the script.

Alternatively, you can get the [spreadsheet time zone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone) and use that in your [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format) function.

```
function getAndFormatDate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet29");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var timeZone = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(); // Get spreadsheet time zone
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(value, timeZone, "dd.MM.yy");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in the time zones. The time zone in the table settings was different for 1 hour